# Postgresql : Transferring data between python code and through SQL table

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm building car parking system, and now I'm doing a car number registration system with inputs in python code.
The problem is that the system registers car numbers and duration in minutes for parking, but it doesn't have a system which would do extra things with duration for parking. Here's the plan to understand everything easily.
Simply: I need to do something with code and SQL that after registering a car and picking time for it to be valid, for example. The car was registered at 2019/09/15 16:00:00, the duration is 30mins. So I would like to insert this to SQL, that at the time 2019/09/15 16:30:00 the duration ends, and the car is no longer registered. Simply again : I should somehow format and insert EXPIRES Row to SQL.

[image: PLAN]

Comment: It's not a good practice to store a column that can be easily calculated from another column.  Perhaps create a view that shows the expiration time by adding regtime + duration?

Comment: @Jeremy that's what I need.